# Pattern Recognition for an Equation of Motion

Tags: kinematics, energy-conservation, mass, potential-energy, spring

I have the following equation of motion describing a series non linear spring-mass-damper system:
[image]
[image]
Since each spring is non-linear, each ith spring has two stiffness coefficients, namely k_i and gamma_i. If I were add a third mass in series to this system, effectively introducing a 4th non linear spring and damper and the corresponding variables m3,k4,and gamma4, what would my new stiffness matrix look like? I know that the dimensions of the stiffness matrix should be 3 by 3, but I cannot recognize the pattern that I must follow to populate the stiffness matrix’s entries. I know that the mass matrix will become [m1 0 0; 0 m2 0; 0 0 m3] and the damping matrix will become [c1+c2 0 0; 0 c2+c3 0; 0 0 c3+c4]. However, I cannot visualize what the stiffness matrix will become. Can anyone see the pattern for the stiffness matrix?

Comment: Take the last row and columns and move them down and to the right, and everywhere you see a 1 make it a 2 and everywhere you see a 2 make it a 3 etc in the subscripts.

Comment: Bravo John! @JohnAlexiou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the stiffness matrix from

$$\small {\rm K}=\begin{bmatrix}\left(k_{1}\gamma_{1}+k_{2}\gamma_{2}\right)x_{1}^{2}+k_{1}+k_{2} & -k_{2}\gamma_{2}x_{1}^{2}-k_{2}\\
-k_{2}\gamma_{2}x_{2}^{2}-k_{2} & \left(k_{2}\gamma_{2}+k_{3}\gamma_{3}\right)x_{2}^{2}+k_{2}+k_{3}
\end{bmatrix}$$

to

$$\small {\rm K}=\begin{bmatrix}\left(k_{1}\gamma_{1}+k_{2}\gamma_{2}\right)x_{1}^{2}+k_{1}+k_{2} & -k_{2}\gamma_{2}x_{1}^{2}-k_{2}\\
-k_{2}\gamma_{2}x_{2}^{2}-k_{2} & \left(k_{2}\gamma_{2}+k_{3}\gamma_{3}\right)x_{2}^{2}+k_{2}+k_{3} & -k_{3}\gamma_{3}x_{3}^{2}-k_{3}\\
 & -k_{3}\gamma_{3}x_{3}^{2}-k_{3} & \left(k_{3}\gamma_{3}+k_{4}\gamma_{4}\right)x_{3}^{2}+k_{3}+k_{4}
\end{bmatrix}$$

and similarly with the damping matrix

$$\small {\rm C}=\begin{bmatrix}c_{1}+c_{2}\\
 & c_{2}+c_{3}\\
 &  & c_{3}+c_{4}
\end{bmatrix}$$